# How to snap line segments to specific angles in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I'd like to draw lines using segments that are restricted to some specific angles. For example, having line segments automatically snap into the closest angle specified, without having to mess with the points coordinates. Is it possible to do it simply, and how?

Here's an example for 45° angles:

[image: A line with segments at 45° angles]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as you click to create nodes. The angles will be constrained to 15º increments.  So, 3 increments of 15º = 45º

Example

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get any angle, measured to 3 decimal places, by dragging out a guide line from either ruler, then double-clicking on it. The resulting dialog box presents an angle setting. This can then be used to place lines as you like, anywhere, at any angle.